# .htaccess redirect folder to another keeping url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need `www.mydomain.com/folderA/` to be redirected to `www.mydomain.com/folderB/` while keeping folderA in the URL.
How should `www.mydomain.com/folderA/.htaccess` file being coded?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folderB/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: No luck. Why should I write folderA in .htaccess file in folderA?

Comment: Sorry,my mistake, I thought your htaccess was in root, I  edited the ans.

Comment: It works, but it gives me a 404, while www.mydomain.com/folderB/ is not a 404.